# npm install failed with node-sass and node-gyp

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, node-gyp, node-sass

When I install npm on my project ionic with Angular. There is a failed install of node-sass/ node-gyp
error show like this :

> $ npm install
>
> > node-sass@4.10.0 install C:\Users\d\Documents\project\app\node_modules\node-sass
> >     node scripts/install.js
>
> Downloading binary from
>   https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.10.0/win32-x64-72_binding.node
>   Cannot download
>   "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.10.0/win32-x64-72_binding.node":
>
> HTTP error 404 Not Found
>
> Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
>         try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.
>
> ```
>   export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234
> ```
>
> or configure npm proxy via
>
> ```
>   npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080
> ```
>
> > node-sass@4.10.0 postinstall C:\Users\d\Documents\project\app\node_modules\node-sass
> >     node scripts/build.js
>
> Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
>   C:\Users\d\Documents\project\app\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js
>   rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags=
>   --libsass_library= gyp info it worked if it ends with ok gyp verb cli [ gyp verb cli   'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe', gyp verb cli
>   'C:\Users\d\Documents\project\app\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js',
>   gyp verb cli   'rebuild', gyp verb cli   '--verbose', gyp verb cli
>   '--libsass_ext=', gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=', gyp verb cli
>   '--libsass_ldflags=', gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' gyp verb cli
>   ] gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0 gyp info using node@12.13.1 | win32 |
>   x64 gyp verb command rebuild [] gyp verb command clean [] gyp verb
>   clean removing "build" directory gyp verb command configure [] gyp
>   verb check python checking for Python executable
>   "C:\Users\d.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe" in the PATH gyp
>   verb `which` failed Error: not found:
>   C:\Users\d.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe gyp verb `which`
>   failed     at getNotFoundError
>   (C:\Users\d\Documents\project\app\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
>   gyp verb `which` failed     at F
>   (C:\Users\d\Documents\project\app\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
>   gyp verb `which` failed     at E
>   (C:\Users\d\Documents\project\app\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
>   gyp verb `which` failed     at
>   C:\Users\d\Documents\project\app\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16 gyp
>   verb `which` failed     at
>   C:\Users\d\Documents\project\app\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5 gyp
>   verb `which` failed     at
>   C:\Users\d\Documents\project\app\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
>   gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:158:21)
>   gyp verb `which` failed 
>   C:\Users\d.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe Error: not found:
>   C:\Users\d.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe gyp verb `which`
>   failed     at getNotFoundError
>   (C:\Users\d\Documents\project\app\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
>   gyp verb `which` failed     at F
>   (C:\Users\d\Documents\project\app\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
>   gyp verb `which` failed     at E
>   (C:\Users\d\Documents\project\app\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
>   gyp verb `which` failed     at
>   C:\Users\d\Documents\project\app\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16 gyp
>   verb `which` failed     at
>   C:\Users\d\Documents\project\app\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5 gyp
>   verb `which` failed     at
>   C:\Users\d\Documents\project\app\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
>   gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:158:21)
>   { gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found:
>   C:\Users\d\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe\n' + gyp verb
>   `which` failed     '    at getNotFoundError
>   (C:\Users\d\Documents\project\app\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)\n'
>   + gyp verb `which` failed     '    at F (C:\Users\d\Documents\project\app\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)\n'
>   + gyp verb `which` failed     '    at E (C:\Users\d\Documents\project\app\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)\n'
>   + gyp verb `which` failed     '    at C:\Users\d\Documents\project\app\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16\n'
>   + gyp verb `which` failed     '    at C:\Users\d\Documents\project\app\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5\n'
>   + gyp verb `which` failed     '    at C:\Users\d\Documents\project\app\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5\n'
>   + gyp verb `which` failed     '    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:158:21)', gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' gyp verb
>   `which` failed } gyp verb could not find
>   "C:\Users\d.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe". checking python
>   launcher gyp verb could not find
>   "C:\Users\d.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe". guessing
>   location  gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
>   gyp verb check python version `C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import sys;
>   print "2.7.16 gyp verb check python version .%s.%s" %
>   sys.version_info[:3];"` returned: %j gyp verb get node dir no --target
>   version specified, falling back to host node version: 12.13.1 gyp verb
>   command install [ '12.13.1' ] gyp verb install input version string
>   "12.13.1" gyp verb install installing version: 12.13.1 gyp verb
>   install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
>   gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check
>   "installVersion" gyp verb got "installVersion" 9 gyp verb needs
>   "installVersion" 9 gyp verb install version is good gyp verb get node
>   dir target node version installed: 12.13.1 gyp verb build dir
>   attempting to create "build" dir:
>   C:\Users\d\Documents\project\app\node_modules\node-sass\build gyp verb
>   build dir "build" dir needed to be created?
>   C:\Users\d\Documents\project\app\node_modules\node-sass\build gyp verb
>   find vs2017 Found installation at: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise gyp verb find vs2017   - Found
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.18362 gyp verb find
>   vs2017   - Found Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64 gyp
>   verb find vs2017   - Found Microsoft.VisualStudio.VC.MSBuild.Base gyp
>   verb find vs2017   - Using this installation with Windows 10 SDK gyp
>   verb find vs2017 using installation: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise gyp verb build/config.gypi creating
>   config file gyp verb build/config.gypi writing out config file:
>   C:\Users\d\Documents\project\app\node_modules\node-sass\build\config.gypi
>   gyp verb config.gypi checking for gypi file:
>   C:\Users\d\Documents\project\app\node_modules\node-sass\config.gypi
>   gyp verb common.gypi checking for gypi file:
>   C:\Users\d\Documents\project\app\node_modules\node-sass\common.gypi
>   gyp verb gyp gyp format was not specified; forcing "msvs" gyp info
>   spawn C:\Python27\python.exe gyp info spawn args [ gyp info spawn args
>   'C:\Users\d\Documents\project\app\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\gyp_main.py',
>   gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp', gyp info spawn args   '-f', gyp
>   info spawn args   'msvs', gyp info spawn args   '-G', gyp info spawn
>   args   'msvs_version=2015', gyp info spawn args   '-I', gyp info spawn
>   args
>   'C:\Users\d\Documents\project\app\node_modules\node-sass\build\config.gypi',
>   gyp info spawn args   '-I', gyp info spawn args
>   'C:\Users\d\Documents\project\app\node_modules\node-gyp\addon.gypi',
>   gyp info spawn args   '-I', gyp info spawn args
>   'C:\Users\d\.node-gyp\12.13.1\include\node\common.gypi', gyp
>   info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library', gyp info spawn args
>   '-Dvisibility=default', gyp info spawn args
>   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\Users\d\.node-gyp\12.13.1', gyp info spawn
>   args
>   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\Users\d\Documents\project\app\node_modules\node-gyp',
>   gyp info spawn args
>   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\Users\d\.node-gyp\12.13.1\<(target_arch)\node.lib', gyp info spawn args
>   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\Users\d\Documents\project\app\node_modules\node-sass',
>   gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8', gyp info spawn args
>   '--depth=.', gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel', gyp info spawn
>   args   '--generator-output', gyp info spawn args
>   'C:\Users\d\Documents\project\app\node_modules\node-sass\build',
>   gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' gyp info spawn args ] gyp verb
>   command build [] gyp verb build type Release gyp verb architecture x64
>   gyp verb node dev dir C:\Users\d.node-gyp\12.13.1 gyp verb found
>   first Solution file build/binding.sln gyp verb using MSBuild:
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe gyp info spawn
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe gyp info spawn
>   args [ gyp info spawn args   'build/binding.sln', gyp info spawn args 
>   '/nologo', gyp info spawn args
>   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64' gyp info spawn args ] gyp ERR!
>   UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION gyp ERR! stack Error: spawn C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe ENOENT gyp ERR!
>   stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
>   (internal/child_process.js:264:19) gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT
>   (internal/child_process.js:456:16) gyp ERR! stack     at
>   processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) gyp
>   ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362 gyp ERR! command "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node.exe"
>   "C:\Users\d\Documents\project\app\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"
>   "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags="
>   "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library=" gyp ERR! cwd
>   C:\Users\d\Documents\project\app\node_modules\node-sass gyp ERR! node
>   -v v12.13.1 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0 gyp ERR! This is a bug in `node-gyp`. gyp ERR! Try to update node-gyp and file an Issue if it
>   does not help: gyp ERR!
>   https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues Build failed with error
>   code: 7 npm WARN angular-ng-autocomplete@1.1.12 requires a peer of
>   @angular/common@^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must
>   install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN
>   angular-ng-autocomplete@1.1.12 requires a peer of
>   @angular/core@^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must
>   install peer  dependencies yourself. npm WARN
>   angular-resize-event@1.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@^8.2.14
>   but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>   npm WARN angular-resize-event@1.2.1 requires a peer of rxjs@~6.5.4 but
>   none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>   npm WARN angular-resize-event@1.2.1 requires a peer of core-js@^3.6.1
>   but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4
>   (node_modules\fsevents): npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
>   Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted
>   {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:
>   {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})win32","arch":"x64"}) npm WARN optional
>   SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: node-sass@4.10.0
>   (node_modules\node-sass): npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL
>   DEPENDENCY: node-sass@4.10.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js` npm
>   WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
>
> added 83 packages from 166 contributors, removed 618 packages, updated
>   191 packages and audited 1597 packages in 52.38s found 2966
>   vulnerabilities (2197 low, 11 moderate, 756 high, 2 critical)   run
>   `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

package.json

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "7.1.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "7.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "7.1.4",
    "@angular/core": "7.1.4",
    "@angular/forms": "7.1.4",
    "@angular/http": "7.1.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "7.1.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "7.1.4",
    "@angular/router": "7.1.4",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "5.12.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "5.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "5.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-path": "5.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "5.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "5.5.1",
    "@ionic-native/native-page-transitions": "5.5.1",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "5.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "5.1.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "4.0.0-beta.15",
    "@kolkov/angular-editor": "^0.15.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^4.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-charts": "3.9.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "2 - 3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "2 - 3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "1 - 2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^3.14.4",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "2 - 5",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^1.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^1.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^2.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "latest",
    "angular-gridster2": "^7.2.0",
    "angular-ng-autocomplete": "1.1.12",
    "angular-resize-event": "1.2.1",
    "cordova-android": "8.0.0",
    "cordova-ios": "5.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "2.3.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.3.3",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.0",
    "ionic": "4.6.0",
    "jspdf": "^1.5.3",
    "jszip": "^3.2.2",
    "lodash": "4.17.15",
    "moment": "2.24.0",
    "mydatepicker": "2.6.6",
    "ng-select": "1.0.2",
    "ng2-ace-editor": "0.3.9",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "5.3.2",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^5.3.8",
    "ngx-dropzone": "1.2.0",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "7.2.1",
    "release": "6.0.1",
    "rxjs": "6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.0.0",
    "stream": "0.0.2",
    "tslib": "1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "0.11.4",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.11.4",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "7.1.4",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "7.1.4",
    "@angular/cli": "7.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "7.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "7.1.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "7.1.4",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "1.2.0",
    "@types/node": "10.12.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "3.1.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "protractor": "5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "7.0.0",
    "tslint": "5.12.0",
    "typescript": "3.1.6",
    "@svgdotjs/svg.js": "3.0.16"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "com.telerik.plugins.nativepagetransitions": {},
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "ios"
    ]
  }
}
```

npm version: 6.14.4

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall Node Js, while installing on one of page, there will be a checkbox to install extra tools, just check it and then click on next. After Node js installation it will open a extra window asking you to press keys, just go ahead with that. After complete installation, do what you were doing in above case. It should work then.

Comment: No such found while installing it to Mac OS.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Live sass compiler]I have same issue but after spending hours i used the Visual studio code extension name **Live Sass-compiler** it solved my problem ,it compile .scss code to .css file in the same directory just import the .css file in component.